# Magento - removing wishlist link in 1.4.2?

Tags: magento

Previously in Magento, the wishlist link was added using the following (in wishlist.xml):

```
<action method="addWishlistLink"></action>
```

And you could override that and remove it using the following (in your local.xml):

```
<remove name="wishlist_link"/>
```

However, in the newest Magento, 1.4.2, they've changed how the wishlist link is added to the following:

```
<action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
```

Anyone know how to remove the wishlist link now they’ve changed how it’s added?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears there's no publicly available way to reliably remove the wishlist link **block** from the layout.  (you can skip to the end for a workaround)

The `addLinkBlock` assumes the presence of the block that's been passed, so using remove in the way you describe results in a fatal error being thrown

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getPosition() on a non-object in /Users/alanstorm/Sites/magento1point4.2.dev/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php on line 112
```

Here's the core code that causes that error

```
app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php
public function addLinkBlock($blockName)
{
    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
    $this->_links[$this->_getNewPosition((int)$block->getPosition())] = $block;        
    return $this;
}
```

This method assumes its going to be able to pull out a block by whatever name gets passed, so we can't just remove the wishlist_link block as we could in previous versions.

The only mechanism for removing a link appears to be the following method on the same block class

```
app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php
public function removeLinkByUrl($url)
{
    foreach ($this->_links as $k => $v) {
        if ($v->getUrl() == $url) {
            unset($this->_links[$k]);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

However, this is done using string comparison, and there's no reliable way (that I know of) to generate a URL Object from a layout file, cast it as a string, and pass it into the method (this would be required, as there are numerous configuration settings that can change what the final string URL will be).  That makes this method not helpful for our needs.

So, what we **can** do it modify the existing wishlist_link block to use a blank or non-existant template.  This way the block still renders, but it renders as an empty string.  The end result is we avoid the fatal error mentioned above, but still manage to remove the link from our selected pages.

The following would remove the link from **all** the pages using the `default handle.`

```
<!-- file: local.xml -->
<layout>
    <default> 
        <reference name="wishlist_link">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>blank-link.phtml</template></action>         
        </reference>            
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Cheers for this. Bit hacky, but that's nothing new for Magento so guess I'll have to go with this for now. Any idea why the change?

Comment: Actually, just tried this and no joy, still seeing the link. Any more ideas?

Comment: I'd say it's not so much a change as an inadvertent bug created by new functionality.  This works for me on a default install, so I'd check if your local.xml is being loaded, and that everything is surrounded by the correct handle.  Once you've confirmed that, add some debug code to the base template class's setTemplate method to ensure the action method is really being called.  Maybe you have another layout update that's overriding this new one?

Comment: Sorry, works fine, I also needed to update my links.phtml. Working now cheers!

Comment: Thans for this, worked nicely, but still feels a little hacky.

Answer (score 3):

In your local.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <reference name="root">
      <reference name="top.links">
        <!-- Remove wishlist link in magento 1.4.x and newer -->
        <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
      </reference>
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the wishlist link from the admin panel System > Configuration > Wishlist > Enabled = "No"

Comment: I don't want to disable the wishlist functionality, just remove the link from certain pages.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your local.xml file.

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <remove name="wishlist_link"/>  
</reference>
```

This works! I have removed Wishlink from Toplinks and wanted to add it back into another block but that doesn't seem possible when you remove it in this way. Sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm years late here, but for all of those people who are still looking for answers to this.

I have a way to work around this issue that is only a bit of extra work but it's not hacky and it gives you FULL control of your top.links block.

Simply unset the `top.links` block and re-create it, it will be empty (no more `wishlist_link` block) and all you have to do is add whichever links you want inside of it! (Do all of this in your `theme/layout/local.xml` file of course).

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <reference name="header">

        <!-- Unsetting the already existing top links block -->
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>topLinks</name>
        </action>

        <!-- Re-creating a new top links block -->
        <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
            <!-- EXAMPLE: Account Dashboard Link -->
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog">
                <label>Account Dashboard</label>
                <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
                <title>Account Dashboard</title>
            </action>
            <!-- You can add any other links that you want -->
        </block>

    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Also remember that for some links like `Sign In` and `Log Out` you will need to reference your `top.links` block inside the appropriate `<customer_logged_out>` and `<customer_logged_in>` handles instead of inside of `<default>` as a guide for this you can look at Magento's `customer.xml` file.

**IMPORTANT:** If there are any modules included in your project that add links to the `top.links` block, those links won't show up because `local.xml` is processed last, so just keep that in mind when using this method :)

I am a Certified Magento Front End Developer with over 3 years of experience and I have overcome LOTS of layout XML headaches to the point where we became best friends.