# Magento Setup Multi-Store Wishlist Error in Layout

Tags: magento

I am attempting to setup a new store on a magento installation.  It is the 2nd website / store on the install and hosted on a different domain and different folder.  The database is the same.

I followed all instructions to configure and setup a new store.  I copied layout, design, and skin files from old store without changing them.  In theory, both stores are running same code.  When going to the new store in a browser, I get the following error:

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data' does not have a method ''  in /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 323

0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'call_user_func_...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 323, Array)
1 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(323): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
2 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
3 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
4 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
5 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
6 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
7 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(60): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
8 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->defaultIndexAction()
9 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(253): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('defaultIndex')
10 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
11 /httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
12 /httpdocs/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
13 /httpdocs/index.php(81): Mage::run('mysite', 'website')

I have disabled Wishlist under Admin > Configuration > Customer and the module output in Admin > COnfiguration > Advanced > Advanced.

Additionally, my local.xml has the following:

```
        <!-- Removes 'Wishlist' link - Default position: 20 -->
        <!-- for Magento 1.3.x -->
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="wishlist/"/></action>

        <!-- for Magento 1.4.x -->
        <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the wishlist link in Magento is a pain and can cause errors. What you can do is follow this answer to set a blank template to the wishlist link so it will not cause errors (see the bottom of the answer for the code):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4424679/823549

Comment: I found that post prior to posting... unfortunately doesn't solve my problem.  The original store works great still...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the configuration line

```
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="wishlist/"/></action>
```

is incorrect.

What happens here is that a block of type Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links calls its function removeLinkByUrl($url). The parameter $url is generated by another function, which is provided by hepler class Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data. The name of the function is missing: instead of "wishlist/" should be "wishlist/someFunctionThatGetsAUrl" . Since no function name is provided, the system can't find it and throws this error

If the goal is to hide the wishlink block, which is expressed in line

```
<remove name="wishlist_link"/>
```

then why not comment out the action config line, which to me seems redundant?

The redundancy may come from an attempt to serve two older Magento versions, 1.3x, and 1.4x. In 1.3x the action config may have been valid, but that does not seem to be so in you current Magento version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the link many ways... in the end I got rid of top links all together and hard-coded the ones I wanted.

Add this to local.xml and remove the top.links section to remove it from the site:

```
 <reference name="root"> 
        <remove name="top.links" />
    </reference>
```