# add to wishlist button shown only for downloadable products only in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have remove the <kbd>add to wish list</kbd> button on product view page but it still shows for **downloadable** products.

Can anybody tell me how can I remove this from downloadable **products** too?

Just look at this two links

- http://www.debreiboerderij.nl/gratis-patronen/de-breiboerderij-sneeuwkol-roma-big-gratis-patroon.html
- http://www.debreiboerderij.nl/scheepjes-softfun-2423-turkoois.html

Comment: +1 for using `<kbd>`!!!!

Comment: Did you take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423631/magento-removing-wishlist-link-in-1-4-2

Comment: i have fix the previous one but now i want to make the checkbox autoselected can you suggest me how can i do this  http://www.debreiboerderij.nl/de-breiboerderij-sneeuwkol-roma-big-gratis-patroon.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you may take look at the following file (for the default theme):
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/downloadable.xml

at Line.217 in the tag , it will add a template file named links.phtml, which belongs to downloadable modules.

You may notice, when modifing the functions related to downloadable products, always pay attention to the files under

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable

, because there's some customizations with the module Mage_Downloadable